# How to call a function in main from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading

in one of my programs with GUI I use multithreading to get background tasks done. The problem with that is that I can't create widgets for my window because the parent (window) is in the main thread and I'm trying to create a widget in another thread. That fails obviosly.

So my question is: Is there a way to call a function in a non-main thread but make it work in the main thread somehow?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does the main thread know what kind of widget to make? Can the *other* thread(s) signal the main thread to make a widget and *send* it widget parameters so the main thread can make the widget??

Comment: @wwi That is actually a good idea. If I could start an endless loop at the end of the init function of gui and declared a tuple as class attribute every thread would be able to put parameters in it and the loop would create the widgets every time the tuple is not empty. Thanks! I will try that as soon as possible!

Comment: To do that, you could use a `Queue` to pass the parameters from the other thread(s) to the GUI thread. If you're using `tkinter`, the typical way to do that (in the GUI thread) is by using the universal widget [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to periodically schedule the processing and removal of anything that's been put into the shared `Queue` instance by the other threads since the last check.

Comment: @martineau I am using Pyqt5. Could you provide and example for that?

Comment: Sorry, no. The part about using a `Queue` would apply regardless, so you "only" need to find some Pyqt5 GUI-compatible way to periodically check and process the contents of the shared queue. `tkinter` doesn't support multithread, but if Pyqt5 does, then you should be able use a [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) to run a queue-processing function.

Comment: As you are using PyQt you can make it with Qt's signals [Some PyQt multithreading tutorial](https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/)